# Maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, django, recursion, django-models, django-admin

When I try to access my admin site for my django project. I get a message indicating "maximum recursion depth exceeded".  I am totally clueless where the error is coming from since I followed the tutorials. What is recurring that is giving me the error.

Error:

RuntimeError at /admin/

maximum recursion depth exceeded

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    <this is not a link> http: /127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     RuntimeError
Exception Value:    

maximum recursion depth exceeded

Exception Location:     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py in get_language, line 216
```

Python 
    Executable:     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents   /MacOS/Python
    Python Version:     2.7.6

```
Traceback:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in wrapper
                return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in inner
                                           current_app=self.name):
...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in reverse
                app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in app_dict
            self._populate()
...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _populate
                    for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from rango import views
from django.contrib import admin, admindocs
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'rango.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^rango/', include('RangoTango.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

) 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.views.static',
    (r'media/(?P<path>.*)',
    'serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
     'rango',

 )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'RangoTango.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'RangoTango.wsgi.application'
```

Comment: What is inside "RangoTango.urls" ?

Comment: looks like you have two url entries with the same route: `index` and `about` are both accessible by 'http://localhost:8000/'. try removing or changing one and see what happens.

Comment: @SohanJain this is not what is causing the problem. The only problem with this two equals routes is that 'about' is never accessible, because 'index' would always fill the request

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicated APP on your INSTALLED_APPS. Remove one 'django.contrib.admin' and it should resolve the problem

Comment: @victorFreitas that did not help. I still get same message

Comment: @ javidazac it is up in the question under urls.py

Comment: @sohan jain nothing happened. I still get the same message.